# Image editing: "Edit Original" and "Replace" buttons missing on old posts

Tags: wp-admin, media-library

I have a site I've recently migrated to a new server. Everything is mostly looking okay, except on existing posts: when we go back to edit a post, and edit media attachments within it, the "Edit Original" and "Replace" buttons are missing.

The file URLs are all correct, and on the server, permissions of both the files and the parent directories are the same on both servers.

If I add a new image to an old post, it works fine; it's just trying to access the buttons on the existing images that's a problem.

**Working**, old server:

[image]

**Not working**, new server:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: I have similar behavior, but it's one site and one page has those buttons and another page doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Experienced the same issue, but not for all images. The issue was migration related. The problem presented itself **only** for images that were not uploaded via the Wordpress media interface, but were uploaded to the new server via FTP.

To fix this issue, I repeated my migration then re-applied theme and design changes.